# Input dispatching timed out (Waiting because the touched window's input channel is full. Outbound queue length: 2. Wait queue length: 52.)

Tags: java, android, mapbox

Already tried the solutions online but nothing seems to be working.

This is what I see in my Android Vitals and its always showing from all of the new users that downloads my application.

```
"main" prio=5 tid=1 Runnable    
  | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 flags=0 obj=0x75387b30 self=0x78d1815c00    
  | sysTid=1978 nice=-10 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7958084548    
  | state=R schedstat=( 48813689050 2924484381 35465 ) utm=4162 stm=718 core=4 HZ=100    
  | stack=0x7fec653000-0x7fec655000 stackSize=8MB    
  | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)    
  #00  pc 00000000003c7d4c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::DumpNativeStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&, int, BacktraceMap*, char const*, art::ArtMethod*, void*, bool)+220)    
  #01  pc 00000000004a5b64  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::DumpStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&, bool, BacktraceMap*, bool) const+352)    
  #02  pc 00000000004bf780  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::DumpCheckpoint::Run(art::Thread*)+844)    
  #03  pc 00000000004a6810  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::RunCheckpointFunction()+204)    
  #04  pc 0000000000374774  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::JNI::NewLongArray(_JNIEnv*, int)+816)    
  #05  pc 000000000009c764  /data/app/co.dibz.dibzparkingsystem-ng0_if-4oA-hli6DFTa5AA==/lib/arm64/libmapbox-gl.so (???)    
  #06  pc 0000000000097d5c  /data/app/co.dibz.dibzparkingsystem-ng0_if-4oA-hli6DFTa5AA==/lib/arm64/libmapbox-gl.so (???)    
  #07  pc 00000000000acdb0  /data/app/co.dibz.dibzparkingsystem-ng0_if-4oA-hli6DFTa5AA==/lib/arm64/libmapbox-gl.so (???)    
  #08  pc 00000000000ace04  /data/app/co.dibz.dibzparkingsystem-ng0_if-4oA-hli6DFTa5AA==/lib/arm64/libmapbox-gl.so (???)    
  #09  pc 0000000000000548  /data/app/co.dibz.dibzparkingsystem-ng0_if-4oA-hli6DFTa5AA==/oat/arm64/base.odex (deleted) (offset 34000) (Java_com_mapbox_mapboxsdk_maps_NativeMapView_nativeQueryPointAnnotations__Landroid_graphics_RectF_2+152)    
  at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.NativeMapView.nativeQueryPointAnnotations (Native method)    
  at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.NativeMapView.queryPointAnnotations (NativeMapView.java:471)    
  at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MarkerContainer.obtainViewsIn (MarkerContainer.java:171)    
  at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.AnnotationManager.getMarkerViewsInRect (AnnotationManager.java:208)    
  at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapboxMap.getMarkerViewsInRect (MapboxMap.java:1275)    
  at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.annotations.MarkerViewManager.invalidateViewMarkersInVisibleRegion (MarkerViewManager.java:485)    
  at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.annotations.MarkerViewManager$1.onPreDraw (MarkerViewManager.java:44)
```

I'm using deprecated Codes like the following:

```
automap.addMarker(new MarkerViewOptions()
                        .position(new LatLng(myMarker.getmLatitude(), myMarker.getmLongitude()))
                        .title(myMarker.getmLabel())
                        .snippet(myMarker.getmCost() + ";"
                                + myMarker.getmIcon() + ";"
                                + myMarker.getmID() + ";"
                                + myMarker.getmDescription() + ";"
                                + myMarker.getmAddress() + ";"
                                + myMarker.getmRatesID() + ";"
                                + myMarker.getmScheduleID() + ";"
                                + myMarker.getmImage() + ";"
                                + myMarker.getmCost2() + ";"
                                + myMarker.getmHoursType() + ";"
                                + myMarker.getmPrimaryHours() + ";"
                                + myMarker.getmSucceedingHours() + ";"
                                + myMarker.getmDistance() + ";"
                                + myMarker.getmCategory())
                        .icon(icon));
```